# How to redirect login urls depending upon user is admin or staff in django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am new in django . I need to redirect login page depending upon the user is admin or staff. if the user is admin i need  redirect in to `/dashboard`. If the staff is longed in  then redirect in to `/Profile` 
How can i do this.

In my view

```
url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'redirect_field_name': 'next'}, name='login'),
```

in `settings.py`:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/dashboard/'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use django's request functionality

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        #your logic here
        return redirect("/admin/")# or your url name
    if request.user.is_staff:
        #your logic here
        return redirect("/dashboard/")# or your url name
```

You can do according to your requirement. First write logic and only when you want to redirect then only check for the user type. This can also be done

Comment: write it in your view... if someone access your view then check it there and redirect according to your user type

Comment: Any other changes in urls.py ?

Comment: No u dont need to change your urls

Comment: To avoid the need to enter the user name and password again after the redirect, adding  the line `login(request, user)` before it is useful.